# Consideration of child education before moving to Australia

Tags: australia, study, children, relocation

I am trying to get PR to Australia, I hope it would take some years.

My child is 2.5 now and she needs to start her pre-KG this June. Once I get the PR I will need to relocate and find a school for her in Australia.

Is there any particular education system is required to get admission in schools in Australia? Or what I should consider about my child education having relocation to abroad in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Australia offers universal education for children. This means that all children between the ages of 5-6 and 15-17 (depending on the state) are legally required to attend school. The government offers a school system for all children. From [Education in Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_Australia):

> Government schools (also known as public schools) are free to attend for Australian citizens and permanent residents, while Catholic and independent schools usually charge attendance fees.

For a school age child in Australia, there are no specific requirements to get admission to a public school. All children are welcome to attend. They don't even need to be able to speak English to start with.

Comment: What an answer to hear :) Thank you @Greg Hewgill.

Comment: "are legally required to attend school." Does that mean home-schooling is not allowed in Australia?

Comment: @MartinBonner [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeschooling_international_status_and_statistics), home schooling is legal in Australia.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Sorry, no I didn't mean to imply that. Home schooling is legal in all Australian states (but the family must register with the state government), and distance education (correspondence school) is also available from the state government and third party providers.